# GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken method in ASP.NET identity generates duplicate security code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

We are using `ASP.net` identity in our MVC application. Whenever user changes phone number or password, we will be sending security code to the user via email or `SMS`. And we will validate the security code against user, if it is valid we will allow the user to change the phone number or password.

We are generating security code using `GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken` method provided by `ASP.net` identity.

```
var securityCode = UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken(
                                                user.Id, model.MobileNumber);
```

HTML

```
   <div class="text-center top-space" id="validate_code_email">
      <button id="send_via_email" class="submit-btn login-btn-align material_button" data-role="button" onclick="sendCodeViaEmail()">Send a New Code Via Email</button>
   </div>
```

JQuery

```
 function sendCodeViaText() {          
        var model = { 'UserId': userIdentityId };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/accountwebapi/SendVerificationEmail",
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (e) {

            }
        });
```

API controller method to send security code

```
  public IHttpActionResult SendVerificationEmail([FromBody] VerifyPhoneNumberViewModel model)
  {
       try
       {
           if (model != null)
           {
               var user = UserManager.Users.Where(a => a.Id == model.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
               if (user != null)
               {
                   var code = UserManager.GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken(
                                                                 user.Id, user.PhoneNumber);
                   UserManager.SendEmail(user.Id,
                                "Confirm your account",
                                                        "Your security code is: " + code);
                   return Ok(new { success = true, PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber, UserId = user.Id, message = C.RESENDVERIFICATIONCODEEMAILSUCCESS });
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return Ok(new { success = true, message = C.RESENDVERIFICATIONCODEEMAILSUCCESS });
           }
           return Ok(new { success = false, message = C.TRYAGAIN });
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           LogError(e.Message, e);
           throw;
       }
   }
```

We are not having issue in generating security code and validating it. The only issue we are facing is `GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken` method generates duplicate code.

```
Click one - Security Code : 123456 User ID : 1 

Click two - Security Code : 123456 User ID : 1
```

After one minute it generates different code

```
Click three Security Code : 123457 User ID : 1
```

So if user continuously clicks it generates duplicate security code. How to prevent this issue? Please help...

Comment: Do you have the code for the Click event handler?

Comment: Yes, on clicking the button we will generate security code and we will send it to the authenticated user to his email or phone

Comment: I mean, can you show in the question at least some parts of it, especially how the security code is incremented. As for how the security is generated, you can choose not to show it, but if it is not too sensitive, it would be great if it can be shown in the question too. This way, the problem might be more easily seen.

Comment: GenerateChangePhoneNumberToken method mentioned in question is an inbuilt method provided by asp.net identity and me too not aware how it is generating security code...

Comment: No, no. I mean the `Click` method... do you have it?

Comment: Once, we can see how the `Click` event is handled, it should be a lot easier to give solution.

Comment: I have updated my question for you

Comment: Hmm... it could be troublesome if it is stateless... Actually, the basic idea would be to introduce a "global" flag `IsProcessing` in your `SendVerificationEmail`. You should set the flag to `true` once you enter the method to avoid the method being re-executed when it is executing.. Maybe you can try that.

Comment: If user clicks button twice I should send security code to his email twice. If I check global variable as you mentioned then there will be mismatch in the number of clicks and number of mails he recieved

Comment: in that case, then you should create a queue to his request. Such that any untreated request would be executed later. It becomes more complex though...

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. Security tokens for phone confirmation depends on `SecurityStamp` on user record, phone number and *time*. Given that phone number and security stamp are not changed, you'll get new code every 3 minutes.

See [source code](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs), method `public static int GenerateCode(SecurityToken securityToken, string modifier = null)`. There is even a comment `// Allow a variance of no greater than 90 seconds in either direction`
And if you go deeper into the code, you'll get more or less this snippet:

```
DateTime _unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan _timestep = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

var delta = DateTime.UtcNow - _unixEpoch;
var currentTimeStep = (ulong)(delta.Ticks / _timestep.Ticks);
```

And timestep only changes every 3 minutes.

If generating multiple identical confirmation codes is a problem I suggest you change your UI to prevent this - once the code is sent, disable or remove the button that asks for this action. From the discussion I understand that this is done client-side via ajax requests - it should not be a major problem.

Comment: We provided button to the user so that if he didn't receive security code in his email or phone he will click that button to receive the code again. So, I cannot change UI and is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: upvote for you because at least i came to know the reason behind this issue

Comment: Well, why do you think there is a problem in receiving the same code twice? You can update `SecurityStamp` on user every time you send this - this will give you different confirmation codes. But this might lead to more problems: there was a delay in first message, so user asked to send second message. First message arrived, user tries to confirm with the first message, but it is no longer valid as `SecurityStamp` is changed => frustration and more sent codes.

Comment: Sending and validating the security code, functionality is working fine except identical code issue. I don't want to introduce more issue by changing security stamp.  Going to analyse more on this...

Comment: Yes, the real question - is identical codes sent out are a problem or an advantage. Think about it. In a few system I run I never had a problem like this, but the set up and intent are the same as you describe here.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned me too never seen this issue in any system that am facing now. So, that I came to a conclusion that it is a issue in my application